# msa1 codec problems

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, codec

So my new job started.  The company provided me with a computer with a Windows Server 2008 operating system and they told me I should watch some Live Meeting recorded instructions and demonstrations about how the system works that I will be working on.

Live Meeting, in case you don’t know, has a very cool feature where you can record a power point and video demonstration and play it back later.  The problem is that the video part does not work for a 64 bit operating system like Windows Server 2008.  An error prompts you to download an MSA1 codec.

After a few attempts to solve the problem, I asked the administrative assistant for a second computer which she gave me.  But it turns out the only one I got was one with a Vista 64 bit operating system and I found I still had the same problem with the new computer.

I have a 32 bit Vista operating system computer at home so I took the files home to see if I could run the Live Meeting recordings there.  To my shock, I got the same error.

That is the problem I have.  Now here are my questions.  Where in the world do I get the codec for MSA1?  How do I install this file on my computer?  Surely there must be some sort of work-around for the computers with the 64 bit operating system.  What are these work-arounds?  I have searched the internet and I have yet to find a solution.

What fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ochoco.blogspot.com/2009/03/convert-your-live-meeting-recordings-to.html?

Comment: That does not help me one ounce.

All you have shown is how to record a video in Live Meeting, not how to play them back.

For all I know, it is not even possible to play them back since I am unable to on at least three different computer systems.

Comment: OK, so there is a converter tool.  I will give this a shot.

Comment: Just as I thought would happen:
72.57%
0x8324c001: Some content was not exported. A codec might be missing. Try playing back the meeting and exporting again.
100%
The export to video has finished, with one or more errors.

Comment: This trys to convert to a video.  But the part of Live Meeting that is already a video needs a codec.  FAIL
"72.57%
0x8324c001: Some content was not exported. A codec might be missing. Try playing back the meeting and exporting again.
100%
The export to video has finished, with one or more errors."

Answer (score 1):

The tool mentioned in the above answer does not work any more. So for
people still struggling with the issue in 2021, most of the links of converter and codecs are dead. The converter is available on alternate site but biggest problem was to get hold of the codecs.After trying tons of options following worked for me on windows 10 64 bit

1. Download converter - the official link is https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30328.convert-and-edit-microsoft-office-live-meeting-recordings.aspx in case it is not working search for it and you might find alternate links for it.
2. Download codec - On running this converter the conversion fails because new version of windows do not have required codec and finding the codec was the most difficult part .Download the scdec.dll from here https://samples.ffmpeg.org/drivers32/newcodecpack/ Register the dll manually using by running the command from a elevated command prompt => regsvr32 scdec.dll
3. Now you can use the converter to convert the live meeting recording into a wmv , select the meeting recording folder and click on convert.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).